# How to efficiently calculate number of possible combinations (when selecting at least one of each type)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, division, brute-force

This is the exercise I am trying to solve:

> **Problem statement**
>
> Jack, the pirate finally found the treasure.He found that there were infinite numbers of coins but he can collect
>   only N coins and the coins belong to R different countries (coins will
>   be different for each country). Jack want to collect at least one coin
>   of each country. Find the number of ways the coins can be collected.
>   Assume that coins of same countries can't be distinguished and the
>   order of the coins is irrelevant.
>
> **Input**
>
> ```
> T: Number of test case T lines containing N and R
> N: Number of coins jack can collect
> R: Number of different countries
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> For each test case print the number of possibilities of selecting Coins.
> ```
>
> **Explanation :**
>
> In a pile of coins he can only collect 5 coins and there are 3 different coins; Let a, b and c be different coins
>
> ```
> (a,a,a,b,c) (a,a,b,b,c) (a,a,b,c,c) (a,b,b,b,c) (a,b,b,c,c) (a,b,c,c,c)
> ```
>
> So jack can collect the coins in 6 different ways. Constraint
>
> ```
> 1<=T<=1000 1<=N<=10 1<=R<=N
> ```

**I couldn't code a way to find all the solutions mathematically, so I tried a brute-force approach, but I recognize it's a wate of resources, especially when n is large.**

```
test_cases = int(input())
for case in range(test_cases):
    solutions = []
    n_r = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), input().split()))
    n = n_r[0]
    r = n_r[1]
    excess = n - r
    if r >= n:
        print(1)
    else:
        array = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 97 + r)]
        for i in range(10**len(array)):
            digits = list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(i)))
            if sum(digits) == excess:
                solutions.append(i)
        print(len(solutions))
```

Comment: This might also be a good question for [codereview.se] for help optimizing your current solution

Comment: The mathematics of some analytical solutions are explained in [this Math StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question can be reworded as:

Given N coins, you need to have at least R coins that are different and N-R coins that can be in a whatever configuration.

The arrangements of $N-R$ coins are then, you can think of this way.

Imagine you have N-R circles and R-1 sticks.
For R = 5 and N-R=11

```
3 - 3 - 5 - 0 - 0
○○○|○○○|○○○○○||
```

which corresponds to 3 coins from country A,3 coins from country B, 5 coins from country C, 0 coins from country D, and 0 coins from country E.

There are R-1 possible positions to choose to place the sticks out of N-R+R-1=N-1 slots, so the total configuration is just N-1 Choose N-R.

So, the answer to the question is:
there is only one possible configuration for choosing R different coins in R slots,and there are N-1 Choose N-R configurations in the slots that's left (N-R slots).

So... `1 times N-1 Choose N-R = N-1 Choose N-R`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer tom. I am having a look at combinations on wikipedia right now to better understand what you wrote. But let's assume this:
I have 2 coins in excess, after having taken one for each country (3).
That should be:
C(3, 2) is that correct? 
That would be 3!/(2!*(3-2)!) and not 6, as it should be

Comment: @Andy N=5 and R=3. N-1 = 4, N-R=2, 4 Choose 2 is 4!/(2!(4-2)!) = 6.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I am so confused, sorry.
Thank you for the great answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll always have one of each included, and for the rest, you need all the ways you can select `N - R` coins, which you can do using `itertools.permutations('ABC', N-R)`

```
import itertools

function Jack(N, R):
    countries = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 97 + R)]
    return [list(p) + countries for p in itertools.permutations(countries, N-R)]
```

Also, because you're dealing with user given values, it's worth adding an `assert` to validate the input values:

```
assert 0 < test_cases < 1000
assert 1 <= N <= 10, 1 <= R <= N
```

Answer (score 0):

To enumerate all the cases, you could use `combinations_with_repetition()` from itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from string import ascii_lowercase

N = int(input('Number of coins '))
R = int(input('Number of countries '))

bins = [ascii_lowercase[i] for i in range(R)]

for tpl in combinations_with_replacement(bins, N-R):
    result = bins.copy()
    result += tpl

    result.sort()

    print(''.join(result))
```

The results from N=5, R=3, are:

```
Number of coins 5
Number of countries 3
aaabc
aabbc
aabcc
abbbc
abbcc
abccc
```

These results are found by first you have 3 coins (one from each country) and that leaves 5-3 == 2 coins to be chosen. The formula is:

`{2 + (3-1)}! / {2! * (3-1)!} == 4! / (2! * 2!) == (4*3*2) / (2 * 2) == 6`

`(N-R + R-1)! / ((N-R)! * (R-1)!) == ...`

EDIT: To just get the number of ways.

```
from math import factorial

N = int(input('Number of coins '))
R = int(input('Number of countries '))

print( factorial(N-R + R-1) / (factorial(N-R) * factorial(R-1)))
```